# Gulp watch tries but exits

Tags: npm, gulp, watch, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I'm having an issue with Gulp I just simply want to process sass files, optimize images and watch changes on said sass files. For some reason it does run the sass and imagemin tasks correctly but then it tries to watch and after several seconds it jus exits gulp and I'm back a command line like if I manually stopped the tasks. I don't get any errors or warnings it just ends. This is the gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'), //import gulp node package
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
imageMin = require('gulp-imagemin');

function errorLog(error){
    console.error.bind(error);
    this.emit('end;');
}

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('scss/main.scss')
  .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }).on('error', errorLog))  
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('imagemin', function(){
    return gulp.src('img/*')
    .pipe(imageMin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('minimg'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  return gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); 
});
gulp.task('default',['sass','imagemin','watch']);
```

On command line this is all I see:

```
[14:02:44] Using gulpfile C:\project-path\gulpfile.js
[14:02:44] Starting 'sass'...
[14:02:44] Starting 'imagemin'...
[14:02:44] Starting 'watch'...
```

Then after approx. 20secs it exits gulp, I tried looking everywhere and use other post fixes and no luck.

Comment: What if you simply tried removing the return statement from your 'watch' task?

Comment: Actually I did had it without the return and was having the same issue, I added the return statement after reading another thread but didn't have any luck.